# In a perfectly balanced binary tree convert from preorder to inorder

Tags: arrays, binary-tree, inorder, preorder

So I have a perfectly balanced (Each node has two children, if it doesn't have any children, it is a leaf node) binary search tree

```
                  1
          2                  9
       3      6         10       11
     4   5  7   8    12   13  14    15
```

and I have that in an array in pre-order

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

now how do I convert my array to in-order or post order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, somehow yesterday I misunderstood your question, or you didn't explain it well. anyway, the thing is that --

> you have an array which contains the nodes of a tree, placed in
>   preorder traversal by the tree; now you want to 'reverse-engineer' of
>   it such that you can build or make a tree again from that array so that you can traverse IN or POST order, whatever you required to do!

now one thing you need to understand when you are making the array from the tree, your array should contain the nodes which have value, as well as the nodes which don't have. in another way, you have to place the null nodes of the tree inside of the array, such that you can differentiate the nodes which have value and the nodes which don't have!! pretty simple!

so, what you need to do is, while traversing the tree, you should follow this two-step--

1. if node has value, put it in array
2. else put -1 in array [-1 denotes null value]

now, after traversing the tree and make the array from that tree, you can decode the array to construct back the tree from the array.

**PROCEDURE TO MAKE ARRAY FROM TREE**

1. DO LEVEL ORDER TRAVERSAL
2. IF ROOT HAS A VALUE, PUT IT IN ARRAY
3. ELSE, PUT -1 IN ARRAY
4. REPEAT, UNTIL ALL NODES, BEEN TRAVERSED

**PSEUDOCODE**

```
FUNCTION encode(TREE root, Array a){
  Queue q;
  q->add(root);
  i = 0;
  a[i++] = root->node;

  while(!q){
     TREE temp = q->front();
     q->pop();

     /* if temp's left node contains value */
     if(temp->left){
          a[i++] = temp->left->node;
          q->push(temp->left);
     }else{
       /*  if temp's left node doesn't contains value */
          a[i++] = -1;
     }

     /* do the same for right sub-tree */
     if(temp->right){
          a[i++] = temp->right->node;
          q->push(temp->right);
     }else{
       /*  if temp's left node doesn't contains value */
          a[i++] = -1;
     }
  }
   return a;
}
```

now you can reverse the algorithm to construct a tree from the array, and after that you can do POST or IN whatever you need!

**PROCEDURE TO MAKE TREE FROM ARRAY**

1. CREATE ROOT

   1.1 PUT ROOT IN A QUEUE
2. TRAVERSE I-TH INDEX FROM ARRAY

   2.1 IF ARRAY[INDEX] != -1 , CREATE NODE ON LEFT

   2.2 ELSE PUT NULL ON LEFT
3. TRAVERSE I+1-TH INDEX FROM ARRAY

   3.1 IF ARRAY[INDEX] != -1 , CREATE NODE ON RIGHT

   3.2 ELSE PUT NULL ON RIGHT
4. CONTINUE UNTIL QUEUE BECOMES EMPTY

**PSEUDOCODE**

```
FUNCTION decode(Array a){
    /* creating root */
    TREE root;
    IF (a[0] == -1) 
         root = createNode(a[0]);
    ELSE
        root = NULL;

    Queue q;
    q->push(root);

    i = 0;

    while(!q){
       TREE temp = q.front();
       q->pop();
       /* if array's index contain value, create node */
       if(a[i+1] != -1){
          temp->left = createNode(a[i+1]);
          q->push(temp->left);
       }else{
          /* else assing null */
          temp->left = NULL;
       }
       /* do the same for right subtree */
       if(a[i+2] != -1){
          temp->right = createNode(a[i+2]);
          q->push(temp->right);
       }else{
          /* else assing null */
          temp->right= NULL;
       }
       i += 2;
    }
}
```

Now you could able to make a tree from the array you have! and can traverse the tree to get IN or POST order traversal!!

HAPPY FRIDAY : )

Answer (score 0):

Is this *homework?*  "In/Pre/Post-Order" is a description of how the tree is to be *traversed,* not how it is *structured.*

Comment: Not a homework, I created the tree in an array like you see in the question. Now I want to do a inorder in that pre ordered array! I could not find it anywhere online. I tried to convert this on my own, but the solution is very inelegant. I hope there is a better solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should know the difference between BT and BST. Binary Tree states it has two children, or one child, or doesn't have a child at all;
     Where Binary Search Tree, is special Binary Tree, that has smaller value in the left part and higher value in right. This property is following each and every property/node of BST.

```
 Now, you have a binary tree, you want to traverse the tree in - IN, PRE and POST order. And consider this is the traversing way, not the structure
 of the tree.

 **Rules of PRE-ORDER:**
 1. Visit -> Root
 2. Process -> Left Child
 3. Process -> Right Child
 4. Continue (until Root is Empty)

** Rules of IN-ORDER: **
1. Process -> Left Child
2. Visit -> Root
3. Process -> Right Child
4. Continue (until Root is Empty)

** Rules of POST-ORDER: **
1. Process -> Left Child
2. Process -> Right Child
3. Visit -> Root
4. Continue (until Root is Empty)

I am assuming, you already traversed in PRE-ORDER.

** IN-ORDER Traversal of your TREE **
4 -> 3 -> 5 -> 2 -> 7 -> 6 -> 8 -> 1 -> 12 -> 10 -> 13 -> 9 -> 14 -> 11 -> 15

** POST-ORDER Traversal of your TREE **
4 -> 5 -> 3 -> 7 -> 8 -> 6 -> 2 -> 12 -> 13 -> 10 -> 14 -> 15 -> 11 -> 9 -> 1
```

EDIT: Visit here to understanding the traversing -> https://medium.com/quick-code/data-structures-traversing-trees-9473f6d9f4ef

Comment: Thank you for all the time you took to write the answer, but the problem is; It is easy to traverse a tree when you actually have a tree. I have the tree in pre-order in my array! what I want is to reverse engineer this pre-order and somehow make the array in the question an in-order traversal